# Scala 3 Match Types and F-Bounded types: "Cannot prove"

Tags: scala, type-level-computation, scala-3, match-types

Given:

```
abstract class Quantity[A <: Quantity[A]]
sealed trait UnitOfMeasure[A]

class Time extends Quantity[Time]
object Minutes extends UnitOfMeasure[Time]

class PowerRamp extends Quantity[PowerRamp]
object KilowattsPerHour extends UnitOfMeasure[PowerRamp]
  
type Test[X <: UnitOfMeasure[?]] = X match
  case UnitOfMeasure[t] => t
```

The following compiles:

```
summon[Test[Minutes.type] =:= Time]
summon[Test[KilowattsPerHour.type] =:= PowerRamp]
```

However if trait `UnitOfMeasure` is declared:

```
sealed trait UnitOfMeasure[A <: Quantity[A]]
```

Both summons fail with:

```
Cannot prove that Test[Minutes.type] =:= Time.

Note: a match type could not be fully reduced:
  trying to reduce Test[Minutes.type]
  failed since selector Minutes.type
  matches none of the cases
    case UnitOfMeasure[t] => t
```

What am I doing wrong?

[Scastie link](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/MOk8ejUeRJmyL90CgIpqxQ)

Comment: [In this Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/QEW0Us2SRs2H1TeiT7zktw), the compiler claims it can't be shown to match or be disjoint from `UnitOfMeasure[t]`, which is odd.

Comment: Removing `sealed` from `UnitOfMeasure` makes no difference.